# GraphQL server recommendation if I don't care much about the tech

Tags: api, server

Looking for a backend server that allows me to specify my API in the GraphQL schema language and hides the database from me.

---

I've recently started a new online app project and am about to settle on GraphQL as the best representation/API of my data.

I have extensive experience with PostgreSQL, Symfony, Doctrine and such, as well as some experience with Meteor, React, Vue, MongoDB, etc.

But I am at the stage where I care much more about my data and actions than about the tech backend. I like [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) for this reason, but it still requires me to define my database structure. I also like the concept behind [PostGraphile](https://www.graphile.org/), but again they build the GraphQL structure from the DB structure and I'd like to do it the other way around.

I would like to define my data structure in the GraphQL schema language and have my backend or some tool translate it into whatever SQL or Mongo structure it is most happy with. Really don't care much about setting up foreign keys right now.

Apollo server seems to allow for this, but requires glueing on the database server manually, or through Prisma, if I see it right.

So is there a no-brainer backend that allows me to specify my schema, get an GraphQL endpoint up and focus on my app? [GraphCMS](https://graphcms.com/) looks like a close fit, but I'd really, really like to host by myself and have the data in my own database.

Suggestions?

---

Preferences: PHP over JS but really not important. PostgreSQL over MongoDB over MySQL, but again not terribly important. Self-hosting over any cloud-based solution, important.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at GRANDstack (http://grandstack.io/docs/getting-started.html)

GRANDstack is a combination of technologies that work together:

1. GraphQL
2. React
3. Apollo
4. Neo4j Database

Mutations are generated automatically by the neo4j-graphql-js library based on your graphql schema.

Comment: very interesting project.